# How to pass map object to rythm

Tags: java, rythm

```
public class Content{
private String previous;
private String current;
 public WatcherContent addPrevious(String previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
    return this;
}

public WatcherContent addCurrent(String current) {
    this.current = current;
    return this;
}

public String getPrevious() {
    return previous;
}

public String getCurrent() {
    return current;
}
}
```

I Have my Content object above and put it inside the map object

```
Map<String,Content> content = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to display the content of map to html using rythm engine

and here is my template

```
@args(){
Map<String,Content> content
}
<html>
<title>content.get("key").getPrevious()</title>
</html>
```

but the rythm engine shows this error

```
   30:  protected String status=""; //line: 12
   >> 31:   protected Map<String,Content> content=null; //line: 12
```

Comment: How do you pass that content into template? Are you using things like  `Rythm.render("/path/to/my/templates", content)` ?

Comment: #green Yes, and I've already figured out how to do it. you may read it here [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/email-template-using-rythm)